# Fast duplicates filtering in T-SQL procedure

Tags: sql-server

I need to store some records in a table. It's crucial the records must be unique. All duplicates must be silently ignored.

I wrote a procedure which accepts a user-defined table type, I send a record collection to it, and I try to have NEW, UNIQUE records stored.

How do I determine unique? I calculate SHA1 from a couple of columns. In my table, I have a `Hash` column. It has `UNIQUE` index constraint.

Here comes the tricky part. Instead of using `IF EXIST(SEELCT ..)` I use `TRY / CATCH` blocks, I let the `INSERT` silently fail on duplicate hash.

So I use cursor to fetch my rows, then I calculate the hash for each row, then I try to insert this row. If it fails, the next row is processed.

It works. It's quite fast. However I'm very disappointed with my identity column.

If I try to enter 3 identical records and 1 new one I get following id-s: 1, 4. I would expect 1 and 2, not 1 and 4. So identity is incremented on each failed insert. I need to avoid it.

I tried to wrap the `INSERT` into `TRANSACTION` and `ROLLBACK` in the `CATCH` block. It does nothing. It works, just the id-s are wrong.

Is there a way to use `UNIQUE` constraint to filter the duplicates efficiently or the only way is using `IF EXISTS` method?

Is using `UNIQUE` constraint really faster than `IF EXISTS`?

**UPDATE:**
The typical scenario would look like 1000 duplicates and 2 new rows. There will be some concurrent calls to this procedure. I just don't want it to slow the server considerably when I'll have like a couple of millions of rows in my table.

Comment: I would think that adding a proper constraint on the table and using the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON` option when you ALTER TABLE [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-index-option-transact-sql) would be preferable to trying to manage this through single row inserts and try/catch blocks on the client side.

Comment: I like IGNORE_DUP_KEY approach, I just set this option to my table and the `INSERT` works almost as expected. Well, the id-s are still borked. BTW, the solution must be entirely within stored procedure due to the project requirement. This option however doesn't give any exception since IGNORE_DUP_KEY explicitly tells DB to issue only a warning signal instead of an exception.

Comment: That's a shame that even with `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` approach you are still running into auto increment issues. Perhaps truncate and load a stage table  with the proper constraints and then [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) into your final table where the keys will be assigned?

Comment: Yep. That's a shame. It would allow a sort of a cool optimization. Now I stuck with the cursor and `IF EXISTS` - however its performance is not bad. Way better then using temporary tables. Checking if the index value exists in table is very fast. The insert is fast with clustered index and no `UNIQUE` constraint. Well, theoretically I can store some duplicates with different id-s, practically the procedure won't allow it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [SET IDENTITY INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql) and control that identity field till the end of insert:

```
SET IDENTITY INSERT ON
CURSOR --increasing also counter for identity column and setting it during loop
SET IDENTITY INSERT OFF
```

By the way, are you sure you cannot avoid cursors?
You could use `EXCEPT` to get only the values that are not already existing and inserting them in only one statement, that would be definitely faster; just to give an idea:

```
INSERT INTO DestTable
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM SourceTable
               EXCEPT 
               SELECT * FROM DestTable)
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to use EXCEPT here, the rows considered duplicate could be not identical. Then I cannot use `*` for `SELECT` because this would try to insert identities and fail.

Comment: I tried to avoid cursors but I couldn't avoid broken id-s then.

Comment: Instead of SELECT * use the columns you need ;for the INSERT you can also define which values and with which order you're inserting them

Comment: I still don't understand how this `EXCEPT` syntax is faster than `WHERE` and subquery. BTW, `WHERE` with subquery doesn't work anyway because the subquery is executed before the first row is inserted, so if my row collection contains duplicates they won't be filtered. The only thing that actually seems to work as expected is cursor and checking the each row for matching hash. Not exactly a rocket, but at least works.

Comment: It is faster since you're addressing all the data in a single command, as SQL has been designed to work better. Today I have no access to pc, Monday I'll try to formulate better